# JavaScript scrolling unpredictable up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, scroll, scrolltop

I've got a big or maybe small problem. I'm trying to scroll my website, so each container slides to a specific position to the top of the website. But, as far as i can see, there is a problem, because if you click the first item and then the next, the script scrolls to the same position, but if you click on a item above the previous clicked, it scrolls to the bottom of the page.

my script for this is a simple anchorscript, take a look:

```
$("a.scrollForMe").each(function() {   // go through all links
var href = $(this).attr("href");
if (typeof(href) == "undefined") { return; }
if ($(this).attr("href").match(/^#/)) {   // if href starts with #
    $(this).click(function() {  // add a click event to it
        var name = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);  // get the anchor link

        // on click, scroll to the a with a name attribute matching the anchor
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("section[name='" + name + "']").offset().top - 420}, 1000);

        //alert ("This height is: " + $("section[name='" + name + "']").height() + " and it's name is " + name);
    });
}
});
```

If you want to see, how its working at the moment, take a look at my website:
http://1st-issue.de/2012/redaxo/#sec10

i hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: em, i know the problem you say, but you should explain what you want, when clicking the next or the previous one.

Comment: Thank you xiaohao for your advice. I'm sorry I missed do explain, but the answer down here has already answered, what I was looking for :)

Comment: 420 was just for testing purposes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably if you use this code it will be better. I tested on a save page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.scrollForMe").each(function() {   // go through all links
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (typeof(href) == "undefined") { return; }
    if (href.match(/^#/)) {   // if href starts with #
      $(this).click(function() {  // add a click event to it
        var name = href.substring(1);  // get the anchor link

        // on click, scroll to the a with a name attribute matching the anchor
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("section[name='" + name + "']").prevAll("section").first().offset().top + 100 }, 1000);

        //alert ("This height is: " + $("section[name='" + name + "']").height() + " and it's name is " + name);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If I can give you an advice, you shouldn't use the href to anchor because the screen jump automatically to the anchor.
With the code code you have added, the screen blinks because the browser go to the corresponding anchor and after execute the scrollTop animation. But it is just an advice.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking the code !! Now it works perfectly. I think the problem was, that I referred to the clicked object and not the Object being loaded. :) And thank you for your advice, I've been looking the whole time for a solution for this problem. At the moment, my cms generates a section with the ID as name for the anchor and a link. Do you know any better solution ?

Comment: Not a complete solution. I though to store the anchor using another way. When the document is ready, you can remove the href and put the reference with the data method of jquery. But I don't know your code so maybe it is more complicated. Or perharps there is a way to disable the default action of the moving anchor.

Comment: the current CMS PHP Code is like this:
`$teaser = '<section name="sec'.$lev1->getID().'" id="sec'.$lev1->getID().'" ';` this is for the section and then `$teaser.= '>
 <h3><a href="#sec'.$lev1->getID().'" class="scrollForMe"><span>'.$lev1->getName().'</span></a></h3>
 <div class="sliderwrapper">';` this is for the link you can click on

Comment: It depends if you want an html w3c compliant or not. I read the w3c documentation about html5 and you can declare an attribute `data-*`. So you can replace `href` by `data-href` for example. And I think you can retrieve the value with http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: I think the problem is, I need this href in the `a` to get my accordion to work, but I also want to use something like `event.preventDefault();` to stop this jumping. Thank you verymuch for your help, Ill keep an eye on it and if I find a solution, I will post it down here!